# In my case, "am I" or "do I"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, verb-forms

"the city is alive and so am I/do I!".....? please help me to find the correct form.. I was gonna go with the first option, until I got contradicted by someone who I usually trust when it comes to grammar, but I know it's wrong this time! Right?

Comment: Think of it this way:  *So do I* - so do I what?  *I do alive*?  That's not right.  So it must be *am*.

Answer (score 2):

"**so am I**" agrees with the first part, "*the city is alive*". Both parts represent a state. "**so do I**" would be possible with "*the city lives*" where both parts represent an action.